# Assessing joint variations of responses in interventional study

Tags: repeated-measures

I have a question. I have several (e.g. VAR01, VAR02, VAR03 ) variables. They are measured twice, one with an intervention  and one without intervention.

I want to test the hypothesis that the greater change in VAR01 (before and after the intervention) will also result in greater changer in VAR03.

Which method should I use?

***EDIT:***

What if I test the hypothesis that the greater change in VAR01 and VAR02 (before and after the intervention) will also result in greater changer in VAR03 and VAR04.

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract the befores from the afters for each pair and variable so that you are looking at changes, then just do a correlation or regression analysis between Var01 and Var03.  This is probably the simplest, though may not be the most elegant.

Comment: Thanks, how about " the greater change in VAR01 and VAR02 (before and after the intervention) will also result in greater changer in VAR03 and VAR04"?

Comment: You could also do this as one or more regression models (possibly a multivariate, multiple regression).

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [profile analysis](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/~efc/classes/biol710/manova/Profile-Analysis.pdf) ( specifically Parallelism)